# Not retrieve value Simple lottery ethereum contract manager method

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity

I'm build a simple app with react but **var manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();**
never retrieve value, how can i wrong please?.

lottery.js

```
import web3 from './web3';

const address = '0x430b45dcf781d58e73CeeA288b4196B6ddeE4d7E';

const abi = [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"enter","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getPlayers","outputs":[{"internalType":"address[]","name":"","type":"address[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"manager","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pickWinner","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"players","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"random","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];
const cont = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,address);
export default cont;
```

App.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import web3 from './web3';
import lottery from './lottery';

class App extends Component {
  
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {"manager":''};
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    console.log("componentDidMount fired");
    var manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();//never set  manager var
    this.setState({manager});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Lottery contract</h2>
        <p>This contract is managed by {this.state.manager}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

web3.js

```
import Web3 from "web3";

const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);//Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);


export default web3;
```

[image: Result view]

please any suggest that help me is welcome, thank

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was to compile my contract on https://remix.ethereum.org/ and to copy the abi from there.

```js
const abi = [ 
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "enter",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getPlayers",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address[]"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "manager",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "pickWinner",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "players",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

there.

I was keeping looking for continue this trainning project and many time I think that I have something configuring in bad way and I test each of technologies that I use in this. At the end test metamask extention and I saw that something is wrong with my metamask, well I uninstall and after that re install it. walla. it's  work.

Sorry if I can not talking some tech detail but my message for some one that have similar problem, it dont give up...hahaha

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seba's answer is what worked for me. Use the Remix online editor to compile and deploy. You can then copy the valid abi

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31864658)